# Understanding Asp.Net MVC Identity and Owin

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, owin

Disclaimer: I have already read and seen LOTS of tutorials/videos and unfortunately am still not clear on how this works. What I know:

1. At application Startup **ConfigureAuth** is executed which contains

   app.CreatePerOwinContext(GE.Core.DbContexts.ApplicationDbContext.Create);
2. This in turn goes to **ApplicationDbContext** class and establishes a connection

   ```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, Role, int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
   {
   public DbSet<User> geUsers { get; set; }


   public ApplicationDbContext(string connString)
       : base(connString)
   {
       Database.SetInitializer(new MySqlInitializer());
   }

   public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
   {
       return new ApplicationDbContext("name=GEContext");
   }
   ```

   }

**Question 1**: is there a way to not establish this connection until the login page appears? OR What if i keep a dummy connection in my we.config which should be invalid as soon as i sign-in and replaced with the actual connection?

After the login page is loaded, i take a schoolCode at Login and want to establish a database connection based on that schoolCode. e.g. name = GEContext_[schoolCode]. My Web.config will contain many connectionStrings like this.

**Question 2** When I Debug my application, every time a page is loaded, Create method of ApplicationDbContext is hit and a default connection

```
return new ApplicationDbContext("name=GEContext");
```

always seems to establish..What's actually going on?

Here is my remaining code:

**ApplicationUserManager**

```
 public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>
 {
     public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
    {
       var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser, Role, int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        ....
      }
  }
```

I have another **GEContext**

```
 [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class GEContext : DbContext
{

    public GEContext(string connString):base(connString) 
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Database.SetInitializer(new MySqlInitializer());
    }
}
```

which works fine from the controller

```
private static string schoolCode = (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SchoolCode"];

 [Authorize]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
       YearRepository repYear = new YearRepository("name=GEContext_" + schoolCode);
    }
```

How do i do the same with applicationdbcontext? but above all questions how does it work?

Comment: You have a seperate database for each school? Just curious, is there a special reason for this? Isn't it easier to merge those to one database and add a school table?

Comment: yes i have a separate and no i cannot merge them

Comment: You may want to create an [IDbContextFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506876(v=vs.113).aspx) instance for the owin context instead.
A `DbContext` is created to be used as is - with its underlying connection. And you are adding one instance within the owin pipeline before the actual page is loaded. If you want to reuse a connection string with the same database context you can add one `IDbContextFactory` instance via owin. If the page is loaded retrieve the factory and create an actual `ApplicationDbContext` via the factory for the current page request.